# Excel or Google Sheets: Sum based on criteria in another column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, sum

I have a spreadsheet which contains two columns with two separate values for each row.  Each letter indicates a value attached to a variable.  The values of the variables change depending on which column they are in.

These are the values if the variable is in the column S1_ST: B=3, C=4, D=4, R=4, W=1, WA=0.

These are the values if the variable is in the column S2_ST: B=2, C=9, D=0, R=6, W=2, WA=0.

I am looking for a formula to return the sum of the value for S1_ST and S2_ST based on the variable entered in those columns.

For Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byxg512qAqFgX2RyQlh3ellJLTA/view?usp=sharing

So, the value in I2 should be 4.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance for the ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vlookup.

[image: vlookup]

You can use vlookup or sumifs.  See my screenshot with the formula indicated.  The number 3 at G1 is calculated from the list of values for the variables.

Answer (score 1):

This formula also works in Google Sheets:

`=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(G2:H="D"))`

It can also be amended to reference the first letter in the column header so that you can copy it to other columns

`=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(G2:H=LEFT(I1,1)))`

Here is a sheet based on your example: https://goo.gl/ufn7YE

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference table with the associations, then you can sum two VLOOKUP functions.

=SUM(VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num),VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num))